# Display (values of) DataAnnotations - Swashbuckle - Swagger page

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is it possible to display the DataAnnotations of parameters on the Swagger page, e.g. the minimum and maximum values?

I've already tried setting the ShowExtensions and ShowCommonExtension to true or calling ShowExtensions(), but it doesn't solve the problem. The Range attribute and/or e.g. MaxLength(20) of a string isn't displayed on the Swagger page.

**Startup (code snippet)**

```
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        options =>
        {
            options.ConfigObject = new ConfigObject
            {
                ShowCommonExtensions = true,
                ShowExtensions = true
            };

            options.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("showCommonExtensions", true);

            options.ShowExtensions();
```

**Frameworks/Packages**

- .NET Core 3.1
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (5.4.1)
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen (5.4.1)

**Controller (code snippet)**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IEnumerable<string> GetMethod([Required] [Range(1, 10)] int value)
 {
```

**Swagger UI**

[image: Swagger UI]

Comment: Possible, yes it is: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=IntParam#/IntParam/IntParam_Get

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Thank you for your reply. It seems the issue is related to V2 of the OpenApi Specification. The provides example is using V2 instead of OAS3, the version which I am using.

Comment: Can you expand on that "OpenApi Specification issue" both have options for maximum and minimum

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Please have a look at more detailed information on the issue page of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore - [#1683](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1683)

Comment: Can you show the version of swagger-ui you are using, there are instructions on how to get it here: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/version-detection/

Comment: I just tried ShowCommonExtensions in .net 6.0 and it causes swagger UI to show min/max values that came from .net RangeAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging...

They do have checks for multiple attributes:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/316ddd0fe6768f470c274a0e93c789b65cf658b9/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SchemaGenerator/OpenApiSchemaExtensions.cs#L12

```
if (attribute is DefaultValueAttribute defaultValue && defaultValue.Value != null)
{
    schema.Default = OpenApiAnyFactory.CreateFor(schema, defaultValue.Value);
}
else if (attribute is RegularExpressionAttribute regex)
{
    schema.Pattern = regex.Pattern;
}
else if (attribute is RangeAttribute range)
{
    schema.Maximum = decimal.TryParse(range.Maximum.ToString(), out decimal maximum)
        ? maximum
        : schema.Maximum;

    schema.Minimum = decimal.TryParse(range.Minimum.ToString(), out decimal minimum)
        ? minimum
        : schema.Minimum;
}
```

But the only UnitTest using range I see is on a model:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/47684caeeaaeb4d887236e61a2ea35e4dc76b958/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.TestSupport/Fixtures/DataAnnotatedViaMetadataType.cs#L26

```
    public class MetadataType
    {
        [Required]
        public string StringWithRequired { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int IntWithRequired { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 12)]
        public int IntWithRange { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression("^[3-6]?\\d{12,15}$")]
        public string StringWithRegularExpression { get; set; }
    }
```

If this is something you truly care about fill in a bug report:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/new

Comment: Thank you for the effort and time you put into the described issue. I've created an issue on the GitHub page of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. Perhaps you can have a look at it, because it contains additional information: [#1683](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1683)

Comment: @Odrai I created a swagger json with what you provide in the issue ... It looks good under my version of swagger-ui: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/62047900_swagger.json#/WeatherForecast/get_WeatherForecast

Must be they (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) are using an old version

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The issue occurs in the current available NuGet package of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (v. 5.4.1). I've cloned the current master source code (which is version 5.4.2) and added a reference to a test project. After some testing, I can say they fixed the issue in the latest (master) version. We just have to wait for a new NuGet release. Most important part is the way Swashbuckle handles the ShowCommonExtensions property of ConfigObject.